# not detecting OnTouchListener for viewgroup with nestedscrollview and recycleviews

Tags: android, touch, android-nestedscrollview, android-touch-event

I am adding touch listener to parent view for to detect swipe gestures. My layout has a nested scrollview and three recycleviews, but my touchevent does not get triggered, i think the parent doesn't get the touchIntercept. In this case i want the constraintLayout to handle the touch event.

**XML**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/table_view_main_constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ui.table_view.TableViewActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_table_view">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_table_view"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorFontWhite"
        android:translationZ="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/content_table_view_layout_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraint_layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraint_layout_spinners"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_table_view_country"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_button_round_home"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:popupBackground="@drawable/shape_spinner_gradient"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_table_view_league"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_button_round_home"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    style="spinner"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:popupBackground="@drawable/shape_spinner_gradient"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner_table_view_country" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/table_view_recycle_view_games"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constraint_layout_spinners" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.53"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constraint_layout_spinners" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/table_view_recycle_view_odds_1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline6"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constraint_layout_spinners"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/table_view_recycle_view_odds_2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline6"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constraint_layout_spinners"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.77"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constraint_layout_spinners" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
public class TableViewActivity extends BaseActivity implements CustomAdapterGames.OnGameClickListener {
    private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_view);

constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.table_view_main_constraint_layout);

constraintLayout.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

    recyclerViewGames = findViewById(R.id.table_view_recycle_view_games);

    adapterOdds1 = new CustomAdapterOdds(this, Games, this, GamesHashMap.get(viewPagerColFirst), SitesList, viewPagerColFirst);

    configRecyclerViewGames(recyclerViewGames, adapterGames);


}
}
```

**Ontouch Method**

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                //   return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                upX = event.getX();
                upY = event.getY();

                float deltaX = downX - upX;
                float deltaY = downY - upY;

                // swipe horizontal?
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // left or right
                    if (deltaX < 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(TableViewActivity.this, "prev", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (deltaX > 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(TableViewActivity.this, "next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(TableViewActivity.this, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                // swipe vertical?
                if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // top or down
                    if (deltaY < 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (deltaY > 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(TableViewActivity.this, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                //     return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending hours on this task, I finally figured out what was causing the issue. I am posting answer so that others can benefit.

This is my `OnSwipeTouchListener` Class which detects touch events using `GestureDetector`

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public final GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    Context context;
    private OnSwipeListener onSwipeListener;


    OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx, View mainView, OnSwipeListener onSwipeListener ) {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
        mainView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        context = ctx;
        this.constraintLayout=constraintLayout;
        this.onSwipeListener = onSwipeListener;
    }

    float firstTouchX;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            default:
                break;
        }
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public class GestureListener extends
            GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                        result = true;
                    }
                } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        //onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        //onSwipeTop();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    void onSwipeRight() {
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Swiped Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        onSwipeListener.onRightwardsSwipe();

    }

    void onSwipeLeft() {
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Swiped Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        onSwipeListener.onLeftwardsSwipe();
    }

  /*  void onSwipeTop() {
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Swiped Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        onSwipeListener.onRightwardsSwipe();
    }

    void onSwipeBottom() {
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Swiped Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        onSwipeListener.onRightwardsSwipe();
    }*/

}
```

Interface for `OnSwipeListener` which you can implement within your activity.

```
public interface OnSwipeListener
{
    //public void onUpwardsSwipe();
    //public void onDownwardsSwipe();
    public void onLeftwardsSwipe();
    public void onRightwardsSwipe();
}
```

You have to `override` gesture detector `onTouchIntercept` in your activity.

```
 @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        onSwipeTouchListener.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

now you can use `OnSwipeTouchListener` for your view.

```
onSwipeTouchListener = new OnSwipeTouchListener(this, findViewById(R.id.nested_scroll_view), this);
```

Comment: I am not sure why this got a negative rating. but only this solution fixed my issue out of all the answers. Thank you.